# Compose FontFamily error: "Variable must be initialized"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add fonts to my app but when I declare the fonts in `Type.kt` file I get this error saying

> Variable 'iranSansFontFamily' must be initialized

Why am I getting this error?

Here's the code:

```
val CustomTypography = Typography(
    bodyLarge = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = iranSansFontFamily,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        lineHeight = 24.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp
    )
)

val iranSansFontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.iransans_farsi_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.iransans_farsi_bold, FontWeight.Bold)
)
```

Comment: *Why am I getting this error?* because of order ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the declaration of the font family must be on the top of typography, like that:

```
val iranSansFontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.iransans_farsi_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.iransans_farsi_bold, FontWeight.Bold)
)

val CustomTypography = Typography(
    bodyLarge = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = iranSansFontFamily,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        lineHeight = 24.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp
    )
)
```